# PDE model of metal rod at temperature=1 plunged into a bath of temperature=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

Consider a metal rod ($0 < x < l$), insulated along its sides but not at its ends, which is initially at temperature=1. Suddenly both ends are plunged into a bath of temperature=0. Write the PDE, boundary conditions, and initial condition that model the temperature of the rod. Write the formula for the temperature $u(x,t)$ at position $x$ and time $t$ for later times. In this problem assume identity

$$1=(4/\pi)[sin(\pi x/l)+(1/3)sin(3\pi x/l)+(1/5)sin(5\pi x/l)+...]$$

holds for all $0 < x < l$

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an example of a heat equation.

Let $u(x,t)$ denote the temperature at $x$ at a given time $t$ of a rod of length $l$.

We may thus describe the heat distribution as
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = a^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$ where $a^2$ is known as the **thermal diffusivity**, which depends on the material which the bar is made of. You can read more about this [here](http://www.labma.ufrj.br/~mcabral/cursos/2015-1/Boyce-cap10.5.pdf).

The above PDE must be considered subject to boundary conditions \begin{align}u(0,t) &= 0 ~~~~~~~ t>0 \\ u(l,t) &= 0  ~~~~~~~ t>0\end{align}
with initial condition $$u(x,0) = 1 ~~~~ 0 \le x\le l$$

You may now solve this PDE in order to obtain the solution of $u(x,t)$ such that your given boundary conditions are met. I would suggest [Seperation of Variables](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/heatSln.pdf).

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that the equation would be solved with the help of the fourier series identity. You have the answer 1 = (identity of sin and cosin), you will have to find the values of x based on that. I will search for an example and post it as an answer if more clarification is needed.